# Repaint components in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, repaint, invalidation

I Have some part of view which show text fields in `JOptionPane`. And there is a button "other". After click on it I need `JOptionPane` repaint itself and show some hidden text fields.

I use GridLayout for my text fields. I tried `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods in the button listener but they do nothing changes.

The `validate()` method works but the size of all components is too small. Seems wrong resizing in the grid panel. In my original code some components are just hiding. I didn't `setPrefferedSize()` or `getPrefferedSize()` because I read it is wrong, but can't figure out how to make right resizing after.

I take my code and did simple as I can, just a part of view.

```
public class AddView {

    private JFrame parentFrame;
    private JPanel addPanel;
    private JPanel gd;

    private JLabel nameLabel;
    private JLabel surName;
    private JLabel skype;

    private JTextField nameTField;
    private JTextField surNameTField;
    private JTextField skypeTField;

    private JButton otherButton;

    public AddView(JFrame parent) {
        this.parentFrame = parent;
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        addPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gd = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 5));

        nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
        surName = new JLabel("Surname");
        skype = new JLabel("Skype");

        nameTField = new JTextField();
        surNameTField = new JTextField();
        skypeTField = new JTextField();

        otherButton = new JButton("Other");

        gd.add(nameLabel);
        gd.add(nameTField);
        gd.add(surName);
        gd.add(surNameTField);

        addPanel.add(gd, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        addPanel.add(otherButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        otherButton.addActionListener(new OtherFieldsAction());
    }

    public int showAddPane() {
        return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parentFrame, addPanel, "Add Contact", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }

    private class OtherFieldsAction implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gd.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 0, 5));
            gd.add(skype);
            gd.add(skypeTField);
            // gd.revalidate(); not work
            // gd.repaint();
            gd.validate();

        }
    }
}
```

This is JOptionPane

[image]

When I click "other" button I have this result

[image]

But I need to get it with right resize like this

[image]

Can you give an advice about how to make right repaint.

Comment: In this case it might be better to disable the components until they are relevant.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson You mean using `JComponent.disable()`? Not sure I  understand it right.

Comment: *"You mean using `JComponent.disable()`?"*  Well, given that method has been deprecated since **Java 1.1,** no.  Try instead [`setEnabled(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled-boolean-) ..

Comment: @Andrew Thompson But components will be visible. I need to hide them until user click the button.

Comment: Then put them in a `CardLayout` with a blank panel as the other card..  But don't try to resize the container - that is confusing to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the [Window#pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) method will work:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddView2 {
  private JFrame parentFrame;
  private JPanel addPanel;
  private JPanel gd;

  private JLabel nameLabel;
  private JLabel surName;
  private JLabel skype;

  private JTextField nameTField;
  private JTextField surNameTField;
  private JTextField skypeTField;

  private JButton otherButton;

  public AddView2(JFrame parent) {
    this.parentFrame = parent;
    initComponents();
  }

  private void initComponents() {
    addPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    gd = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 5));

    nameLabel = new JLabel("Name");
    surName = new JLabel("Surname");
    skype = new JLabel("Skype");

    nameTField = new JTextField();
    surNameTField = new JTextField();
    skypeTField = new JTextField();

    otherButton = new JButton("Other");

    gd.add(nameLabel);
    gd.add(nameTField);
    gd.add(surName);
    gd.add(surNameTField);

    addPanel.add(gd, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    addPanel.add(otherButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    otherButton.addActionListener(new OtherFieldsAction());
  }

  public int showAddPane() {
    return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parentFrame, addPanel, "Add Contact", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
  }

  private class OtherFieldsAction implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      gd.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 0, 5));
      gd.add(skype);
      gd.add(skypeTField);
      // gd.revalidate(); not work
      // gd.repaint();
      // gd.validate();
      SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component) e.getSource()).pack();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    new AddView2(f).showAddPane();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call setPreferredSize() of the added components to get the right sizes you need.